# JavaFX MediaPlayer with HTTPS support

Tags: javafx, https

I just started to implement a `MediaPlayer` in `Java` using `JavaFX`. I was pretty sure about `HTTPS` support in `MediaPlayer` but after getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported protocol "https"
```

I have found that JavaFX doesn't offer support for `HTTPS`.

Is there any alternative for MediaPlayer with `HTTPS` support, I couldn't find one available to use, I want o stream music files from Cloud ?

Comment: See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091132

Comment: What would be the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX MediaPlayer supports HTTPS since openjdk 8u72 [released in January 2016](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/new-release-jdk-8u71-and-jdk-8u72).